# Pandas to MYSQL index=False keeps error "unknown column"

Tags: mysql, pandas, dataframe, sqlalchemy

my sqlalchemy string is:

```
sql_insert.to_sql(name='Table1', con=engine, if_exists = 'append', index=False)
```

return error

> (mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError) 1054 (42S22): Unknown column
> 'Unnamed: 0' in 'field list'

there is no specific index in df, just usual Pandas sequential
how make sql to ignore it?

p/S/
with index=true it returns 'unknown column index'

Comment: There is a column ``Unnamed: 0`` in the dataframe which does not exists in DB, try this ``sql_insert.drop(columns = ['Unnamed: 0'])``

Comment: no, pandas cannot drop it

Comment: I mean I've tried, it is just the sequential that got to be there. I don't understand how to get rid of in sql. In Mysql table there is self-incrementing index, I don't need these numbers

Answer (score 0):

Well, it didn't workout anything I have tried, so I just made sql with specific columns to be used.
Still don't know what happened.